# why segmentation fault (core dumped) show up at end

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

i don't know why this sgementation show up at end of my output

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
char** FileOpen(char *path );

int main(void)
{
char **lines =FileOpen("filename");
for(int i = 0 ; i < strlen(*lines) ; i++)
printf("%s\n",lines[i]);
    return 0 ; 
}
char** FileOpen(char *path)
{
    FILE * fileshow = fopen(path,"r");
    if(!fileshow)
    {
        printf("erorr trying open file %s",path);
        exit(1);
    }
    char**  lines = malloc(100 * sizeof( char* ));
    char buff[1000];
    int i = 0 ;
    while(fgets(buff,1000,fileshow))
    {
        //put null in end of str to show the end of string
        buff[strlen(buff)-1]= '\0';
        //geting string len to form the size of str
        int slen = strlen(buff);
        char *str = malloc(slen+1 * sizeof(char));
        //copy the string into the str
        strcpy(str,buff);
        
        lines[i]= str;
        i++;
    }
    return lines;
}
```

output:
hey how are you bro
hey how are you bro
hey wow
hey how are you bro
hey wow
hey so
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: `for(int i = 0 ; i < strlen(*lines) ; i++)` looks fishy, no NULL in `lines`

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but remember basic arithmetic precedence: `slen+1 * sizeof(char)` is really  `slen+(1 * sizeof(char))`. Not that it matters in this case as `sizeof(char)` is defined to *always* be `1`.

Comment: Output is odd since the printf has a \n in it and the output doesn't.

Comment: `strlen(*lines)` is the length of the first line.  It is not the number of lines in the file.

Comment: Error messages should be written to stderr and be informative: `if(!fileshow){perror(path); ...`

Comment: As for your problem, use a *debugger* to catch the crash as and when it happens, and locate where in your code it happens..

Answer (score 1):

You got to do 2 things:

As there is no NULL termination for `lines` in function `FileOpen` what you get when access `lines` beyond allocated memory is undefined behavior, `strlen` will not save you because you are accessing invalid memory.
So,

1. Add `lines[i]= NULL;` in `FileOpen` function before returning from it.

```
char** FileOpen(char *path)
{
    /* your code */
    while(fgets(buff,1000,fileshow))
    {
       /* your code */
       i++;
    }
 lines[i]= NULL;
 return lines;
}
```

check for NULL when printing from `lines` instead of checking with `strlen(*lines)`
2) Replace `for(int i = 0 ; i < strlen(*lines) ; i++)` with `for(int i = 0 ;lines[i] != NULL; i++)` in `main` Function

Comment: @SergeBallesta, sorry copy paste mistake i meant `lines[i]`

Comment: Only a matter of taste, but I find `lines[i] != NULL` easier to read. Of course, it is now perfectly correct...

Answer (score 0):

many problems in this snippet of code...

1. malloc is missing free(..).. nowhere is there a release of memory.. so memory leaks.
2. open file is not closed..
3. strlen() will search for 0. if it is not found in first 1000, it will continue to search till it finds one, and then it will write 0 on that (place-1)... and that could be anywhere.. that is a possible seg fault.. even reading outside your mem space can trigger seg fault..
4. fgets() will return a null terminated string already, so you don't need to manually add it..
5. you're allocating 100 lines. if file has less, you're still trying to print 100 lines. And those pointers are not set. You're printing from random memory locations and that triggers seg fault..

Comment: When you say "strlen() will search for 0. if it is not found in first 1000, it will continue to search..." could seem a little misleading, as you don't say where you get that number `1000` from. You should say that it's the size of one of the arrays. But since it's passed to `fgets` with a correct size, then if `fgets` succeeds the array is guaranteed to have the null-terminator.

Comment: yeap.. 3 and 4 are mutually exclusive.. i put it in three, so the person posting the question will think about strlen next time, when he's using smthg else than fgets...